# NullPointerException for OnClickListener android Java

Tags: java, android, canvas

I feel bad for asking about this but for 2 hours now I can't find any way to solve this:
**The Problem: ** I have set up a canvas area(where i plot a drawable figure) and a button below the canvas area.
In my AnimatedView class I want find the button and give it an onClickListener, but it returns a NullPointerException.

my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">

<com.example.julle.bounce.AnimatedView
    android:id="@+id/anim_view"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/anim_view"
    android:id="@+id/button_jump"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Jump"/>
```

my code for AnimatedView.java:

```
    package com.example.julle.bounce;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnimatedView extends ImageView{
    private Context mContext;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    private int xVelocity = 10;
    private int yVelocity = 5;
    private Handler h;
    private final int FRAME_RATE = 30;
    boolean jump=false;

    public AnimatedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)  {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_jump);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jump=true;
            }
        });
        h = new Handler();
    }
    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate();

        }
    };
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ball);
        if(jump==true) {
            if (y < 0) {
                y = this.getHeight() / 2;
            } else {
                y += yVelocity;
            }
            jump=false;
        }else{
            y= this.getHeight()/2;
        }

        c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);
        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
    }
}
```

and my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.julle.bounce;

import ...


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

I believe I've realised the problem: the buttons are existent in the MainActivity class but not in my AnimatedView class. Allthou it might be very simple, I'm not sure how to solve that.
Thank you for all replies!

Sorry, totally forgot that I changed the code. AnimatedView is updated:
The line that gives NullPointException is line 26 in AnimatedView: button.setOnClickListener...

logcat:

```
02-24 14:47:32.005  31934-31934/com.example.julle.bounce E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.julle.bounce/com.example.julle.bounce.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.example.julle.bounce.AnimatedView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.example.julle.bounce.AnimatedView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.julle.bounce.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.julle.bounce.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.julle.bounce.AnimatedView.<init>(AnimatedView.java:26)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.julle.bounce.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you add the StackTrace of the NullerPointerException, including the code of the line that is mentioned in the error?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry Kevin, totally forgot to add those! I've edited my post now. My brain is exhausted.

Comment: have you checked the reference variable  `button` ? I mean what are you getting in it . after calling `button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_jump);`

Comment: In your StackTrace it states the NullPointerException is at line 26 (I'm assuming `button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_jump);` if I counted correctly. This could be null when you forget the add the `setContentView(...)` method before calling `findViewById`. This `setContentView(...)` method is mostly added in the `onCreate` method of all your Activity-Views (directly after the super-call). I see you've added it in the MainActivity though.. Hmm.. Is MainActivity your only Activity / Screen? And where/how do you create the AnimatedView in your Activity?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I checked the variable button and it turns out to be null.
I only use the codes which I've linked here, pluss the AndroidManifest.
I followed an example code of a ball moving around on a canvas and bouncing on the wall and tried to modify it.
I don't create the AnimatedView in my Activity, I've assumed it's created by the xml (but I'm very uncertain).

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a reference to your button from main activity to AnimatedView class.

```
package com.example.julle.bounce;
import ...
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewByID(R.id.button_jump);    
        AnimatedView av = (AnimatedView)findViewByID(R.id.anm_view);
        av.setJumpButton(btn);
    }

}
```

You will need to add the `setJumpButton` method in your AnimatedView class.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem, so my suspicion was right. I just did not know how.